# What is the SVD of the 1x1 matrix with entry $-1$?

Tags: singular-values

Question as the title. Consider the $1 \times 1$ matrix $M$ whose single entry is $M_{11} = -1$.

What are the factors in the SVD of $M$? Keep in mind that singular values are non-negative by convention.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: $-1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ or $1 \cdot 1 \cdot -1$.

Comment: $-1=1\cdot 1\cdot (-1)$